# Set -Clipboard -path on remote connected computer

Tags: powershell

I am typing the following command in `Windows Powershell` into a remote connected computer:

(code noted below)

I am getting the error message in `windows Powershell` :
Set-Clipboard : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Q' does not exist.
HOWEVER, if I do the same when directly connected than the code works fine.
Could you please advise.
Thanks

```
Set-Clipboard -Path "Q:\Myname X\2019\07- Mon\City Name Job Nbr   XXX 00-99"
```

Comment: Yes, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating a bit because you didn't provide the command line you used to connect to the remote machine. Probably the `Q:` drive represents a mapped network drive (unless you have a *lot* of USB/SATA drives connnected). You can confirm by running `net use` at a command prompt to show all the mapped drives and Remote/UNC paths. It should look like this

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connected    Q:        \\server\share\           Microsoft Windows Network
```

You were probably remotely connected with the same account you use to log in, but it doesn't map all the drives when you are using a remote session. You can try to either map the drive in the remote session with `net use q: \\server\share` or you can try to use the full UNC path in your command line:

```
Set-Clipboard -Path "\\server\share\Myname X\2019\07- Mon\City Name Job Nbr   XXX 00-99"
```

Where `Server` and `Share` are the values you got from the `net use` Remote  column.